# Play games sign-in not showing option to select account

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to sign-in user using play games services but it keeps failing. It doesn't even show the popup to select the account to sign in.

I have successfully linked my app with the developer account and also included required dependencies but it is still not working

[image: project gradle]
[image: app gradle]

Here is my code, please help

```
 private static final int RC_SIGN_IN =  1 ;
  private  GoogleSignInClient  mGoogleSignInClient;
  private  GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new
                GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            //    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}


 private void signInSilently() {
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
        signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        signInSilently();
    }



    private void startSignInIntent() {
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
        Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // The signed in account is stored in the result.
                GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            } else {
                String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                 //   message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

   startSignInIntent();

    }
```

I have only included sign in process steps

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: You might want to look at the logcat of your app to see if there is any useful logging there, and if there is include it in your question

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add this in the Manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```